$e(H)\leq 2n^2$ for triangle free tripartite graphs
show that if $H$ is a triangle-free tripartite graph with $n$ vertices
in each class then $e(H)\leq 2n^2$.
Remark : I can see that the equality is achieved when 2 pairs of the three vertex classes are complete bipartite.
I have got a hint that "for a bipartite graph $G$ with $n$ vertices in each class, if $e(G)>(k-1)n$ then $G$ contains $k$ independent edges". I can already prove the hint but still have no idea how to apply it to the main question.

What is $e$ in this context?

@DamianPavlyshyn I think it is the number of edges.

As in koifish's answer, assume $e(G)>2n^2$ and let the tripartiton be $G=(A,B,C)$. Suppose there are $x$ edges between $B$ and $C$ and assume that $(k-1)n < x \le kn$. Then  $$e(A, B\cup C) = e(G) - x > 2n^2 - kn = (2n-k)n. $$
So there exists a vertex in $A$ with degree strictly larger than $2n-k$ (consider average degree in $A$). However, since $x > (k-1)n$, there is a matching of $k$ edges in $e(B,C)$. Now try and understand why this makes a triangle.

This looks nice and legit, thanks.
